# Fedex 'Ground' shipping method not showing in frontend

Tags: checkout, shipping, shipping-methods, fedex

I am on Magento Enterprise ver. 1.12.0.2

I enabled Fedex 'first standard overnight', '2 day', 'smart post', 'ground', and 'international economy' in the Admin for my demo site.

The only shipping methods that are showing when I go to checkout in the frontend are first standard overnight, 2 day and smart post.

Why aren't ground and international economy showing up as shipping methods in checkout?

Answer (score 4):

With regards to Ground if you have the Set Residential to Yes then FedEx will not return Ground, it will only ever return Home Delivery.

If International Economy is not showing then for the goods you have in the cart and the destination you are specifying its not an available option. I suggest go enter direct into FedEx exactly the same weight and destination then see what it says there.